# URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings bin laravel; Socialite

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-socialite

I'm using socialite for facebook login but i'm getting this error [image]

In services.php i have

```
   'facebook' => [
        'client_id' => 'XXXXXXXXXX',
        'client_secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        'redirect' => 'https://XXXXXXXXXXX.in/auth/facebook/callback',
    ],
```

Same i have in site url :

https://XXXXXXX.in/

In Valid OAuth Redirect URIs :

```
https://XXXXXXX.in/auth/facebook/callback
```

Any Solution Please,Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove CSRF for callback route

`App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken`

add your route name in
`$except = []`

Comment: It was working on localhost as i change the live url it is not working